# Checking input in VideoCapture in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv

I have imported OpenCV into Android Studio and created an EditText option for the user to input their camera's streaming URL.

I want to use VideoCapture in OpenCV to get the video feed from the camera but first I want to check whether the inputted streaming URL is valid and give an appropriate output. Something along the lines of:

```
if (VideoCapture(input) == true)
{
    // toast camera detected
}
else
{
    // toast camera not detected
}
```

I am unsure of the exact syntax to do this and would highly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `URLUtil` to validate the URL as below.

```
 URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

It will return `True` if URL is valid and `false` if URL is invalid.

```
if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url))
{
    // toast camera detected
}
else
{
    // toast camera not detected
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I wanted to use VideoCapture in OpenCV. Also the "url" I was referring to is not a standard url like "stackoverflow.com" but instead something like "http://192.168.137.191:5000/feed1". Will this work for that?

Comment: yes it will, if this url is providing you stream

Comment: if you found this answer usefull you can mark it as answer

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try it out in a while and tick the answer if it works!

Comment: good if its work for you you can mark it as answer